# How to suppress/redirect grep background errors?

Tags: linux

I run grep searches often but sometimes it takes so long I write to a file instead as a background task but it still has output for apparently errors (I think). For example:

```
grep -rl word . > grep-word.txt &
```

So this runs it in the background and lets me input new commands while it's running but then it randomly pops up messages like this:

```
grep: ./var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such device or address
```

How do I get it to suppress or redirect these errors?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming bash or sh (you don't say what shell you're calling this from):

```
grep -rl word . > grep-word.txt 2> /dev/null &
```